# airflow pass jinja template to dag parameters

Tags: airflow

I am trying to pass jinja template to the DAG constructor. As the airflow best practice suggest don't call Variables outside the execute method.

Below is the code snippet.

```
 dag = DAG(
        dag_id=dag_id,
        schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
        dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=max_dagrun),
        template_searchpath='{{var.value.sql_path}}')
```

But its failing to parse this.

Any suggestion how to pass these type of variables ? These are passed to dags not to the airflow operators.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to create a env variable. called sql_path, then u can use it in here